# SQL cross join query slower than expected, refactoring ideas needed

Tags: oracle, database-performance

This query works but takes 5000 miliseconds.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(case 
        when ((TRUNC(OPEN_DATE) <= thedate and TRUNC(END_DATE) > thedate) or(TRUNC(OPEN_DATE) <= thedate and END_DATE Is Null)) then 1 
        else 0 
        end) as Open  
From ( 
    select * 
    FROM PROJECT 
    WHERE 
        PROGRAM_NAME = :program   
        AND ACTION_FOR_ORG = :orgName 
    )   
    cross join ( 
        select add_months(last_day(SYSDATE), level-7) as thedate 
        from dual 
        connect by level <= 12  
    )  
GROUP BY thedate
ORDER BY thedate
```

If I copy the subquery to its own table

```
create table test_project as  
select * FROM PROJECT WHERE PROGRAM_NAME = :program   
AND ACTION_FOR_ORG = :orgName
```

then do the above query but the subquery is on the copied table as:

```
From ( select * FROM test_project WHERE PROGRAM_NAME = :program   
AND ACTION_FOR_ORG = :orgName )
```

the query takes 10 milliseconds

The query produces a count of how many projects were open in that month over the past 5 and future months (count of open projects for furture months will just equal todays months totals) based on comparing `OPEN_DATE` to `END_DATE`

Is there a way to rewrite the original query for optimal performance?

## EDIT

OK, I created a second table which is a full copy of the project table (well view) that I was allowed access to.  The table copy took about 5 seconds. Using the full set of data and either my sql query or from Egor below, the query is super fast. Something is up with the view.  Trying to spit out explain plan using the View in the subquery I get insufficient privileges.  Here is the explain plan using a full copy of the view

```
 Plan hash value: 3695211866

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id  | Operation                        | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|     Time     |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |             |   637 |  1277K|   163   (2)| 00:00:02 |
 |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                   |             |   637 |  1277K|   163   (2)| 00:00:02 |
 |   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                  |             |   637 |  1277K|   163   (2)| 00:00:02 |
 |   3 |    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN          |             |   637 |  1277K|   161   (0)| 00:00:02 |
 |   4 |     VIEW                         |             |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  5 |      CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|             |       |       |              |          |
 |   6 |       FAST DUAL                  |             |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |   7 |     BUFFER SORT                  |             |   637 |  1273K|   163   (2)| 00:00:02 |
 |*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL           | COMMIT_TEST |   637 |  1273K|   159   (0)| 00:00:02 |
```

---

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

---

```
5 - filter(LEVEL<=12)
8 - filter("PROGRAM_NAME"='program_name' AND "ACTION_FOR_ORG"='action_for_org')
```

Note

---

```
- dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Explain Plan using live table
[image]

Comment: "If I copy the subquery to its own table"..and how long does that table take to create? can you post the explain plan of the original query?

Comment: not sure how long it took to create, but for the query 220 ms to do "select * FROM PROJECT WHERE PROGRAM_NAME = :program AND ACTION_FOR_ORG = :orgName". How do I get the explain plan? I'm using Eclipse DataTools plugin to run a sql scratch pad. I have SQL Plus installed but don't really use it

Comment: I figured out how to generate the explain plan, however I get " insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view"

Comment: "The table copy took about 5 seconds." so the time taken in all variants of the query that involves the base view and not the copy is scanning the table(s) involved in the view. in the view, are `program_name` and `action_for_org` on the same base table? if so is there a composite index available on them (you should run the explain plan that's failing as the owner of the view so that you dont get the privilege error)

Comment: added explain plan.  By the looks of it program_name is not in the base table

Answer (score 1):

```
with
   PRJ as (
      select /*+ NO_UNNEST */ 
         trunc(OPEN_DATE) as OPEN_DATE,
         nvl(trunc(END_DATE), sysdate + 1000) as END_DATE
      from
         PROJECT
      where
         PROGRAM_NAME = :program
         and ACTION_FOR_ORG = :orgName
   ),
   DATES as (
      select
         add_months(trunc(last_day(SYSDATE)), level-7) as thedate
      from dual
      connect by level <= 12
   )
SELECT
   thedate,
   sum(case when thedate between open_date and end_date then 1 end) as Open
FROM
   DATES, PRJ
GROUP BY thedate
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: your query looks nice and clean, but still takes 5011 ms.  Does it matter that PROJECT is a view I am allowed to access to?

Comment: @jeff - Try `PUSH_SUBQ` hint.

Comment: 5091 ms. using PUSH_SUBQ.  I am new to these hints but I think I am appying them correctly.  I am using Eclipse Datatools to test sql query before applying them in my Java Web application which graphs the open projects.  I think users will get frustrated waiting 5secs for a simple graph.  I need to run this in SQL+ and get the explain plan. Will try and figure that out next.

Comment: if I put subquery with a UNIQUE in first select it drops to 1000ms. "nvl(trunc(END_DATE), sysdate + 1000) as END_DATE from ( SELECT UNIQUE * from PROJECT where PROGRAM_NAME = :program and ACTION_FOR_ORG = :orgName) ), DATES ..."